# Higgs bundles and Variation of mixed Hodge structures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory

As we know that: A polystable Higgs bundles $(E, \theta)$ with vanishing Chern classes is fixed by $\mathbb{C}^*$-action iff it comes from variation of Hodge structures.

Q: Is there a conterexample for the extended version of above fact? I.e is there a semistable Higgs bundle $(E, \theta)$ with vanishing Chern classes and fixed by $\mathbb{C}^*$-action that does not come from variation of mixed Hodge structures?